# Count number of days in multiple date ranges without counting the overlaps

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table that describes when a some racing cars in a pool of cars are out for modification. The table describes the start and end dates for each modification, and sometimes multiple modifications happen on overlapping dates. I want to know the **total number of days** a **particular car** is unavailable within a **certain year**.

***Worksheet:***

[image]

In the example above, I want to count the days the car is unavailable in 2019 in the `AC:AD`, `AG:AH`, `AK:AL` and `AO:AP` ranges, without counting overlapping days. The result for Car 1 should be 5 days.

Stackoverflow have many similar problems, but I have yet to find one where you have to count the dates like this.

Answer (score 0):

You must have searched in a rather haphazard manner if you haven’t found an answer to this question.  Just checked myself and it takes about a minute of Googling.  You also didn’t show your attempt at solving the problem so I’m only going to point you at the right direction without showing you the whole solution.

It's an array formula so has to be entered with Control-Shift-Enter:

```
 =COUNT(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE(B2:B4^0),
 (TRANSPOSE($A$8+ROW(A1:INDEX($A:$A, $B$8-$A$8+1))-1)>=$A$2:$A$4)*
 (TRANSPOSE($A$8+ROW(A1:INDEX($A:$A, $B$8-$A$8+1))-1)<=B2:B4))^0)
```

[image]

Comment: I have spent quite some time on this. If you have a link to one of the solutions you found on google, I would very much appreciate it. The problem is that the data in your example is listed downwards in the spreadsheet. I have all the data on multiple columns in a single row.